# Impossible to copy snippets in EmEditor 20.9

Tags: code-snippets, emeditor

After upgrading from EmEditor 20.8.1 to 20.9, I can no longer copy snippets. When I select, copy and paste a snippet, I end up with a snippet in which the fields 'name', 'trigger', 'tips' and 'text' have a value of -1 and the other fields are empty.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Please email bug reports to tech @ emurasoft.com. This issue will be fixed on the next version of EmEditor.

Comment: Done. Feel free to delete this question.